# Multiple file uploader in HTML5 -- browser support?

Tags: file-upload, air, html, cross-browser, multifile-uploader

I read that the HTML5 spec introduced the ability to select multiple files in an upload form. What browsers currently support this? Does Adobe AIR support it?

Bonus question: Is there a JavaScript library that takes advantage of this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 3.6, soon to be released, will have it as well, along with some other file-related goodies:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/

It is also supported by Chrome 3.

I have no info on Adobe Air, but it might be so, since the feature has been in Webkit nightly for more than a year.

Answer (score 3):

Opera has supported this feature since 2006.

Answer (score 1):

afaik Safari 4 is the only browser that supports this feature.  I dont know about your other questions.

Comment: Wrong, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 3+, Opera and Safari 4+ support HTML5 multiple file upload.

Comment: @Jonathan, at the time of this question (dec 28, 2009) firefox 3.6 had not yet been released.  You should add your own answer to give more information.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that, You're right did't notice the date. Do you want me to delete my comment?

Answer (score 0):

Chome developer builds now support this attribute! :)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I disagree. This is part answering the question.