# How can you find out if a specific HTML 5 feature is implemented in a specific browser version?

Tags: html

I imagine there must be out there a website that collects information about HTML 5 feature and what browsers version started to support them.

This might be a good way to decide based on your website profile, if you can apply that HTML 5 feature without a fallback for your visitors.

Do you know such a site/resource ?

For example I want to know what browsers support the multiple upload feature for inputs and what browser version was the first.

### Update

I'm not pleased with the sites suggested so I'm opening a bounty.

Suggestions so far:

Html5Test,

Caniuse,

modernizr.com,

QuirksMode

### Update 2

Some people don't understand the question. I need to implement the multiple upload feature. I know from analytics what browser are they using ( I know this is not 100% correct ).

I'm willing to sacrifice some of the visitors by not offering some advance features but **I need to understand how big is this procent**. I'm NOT trying to DETECT in anyway the browser. It's a similar approach with other sites that dropped IE 6 support.

So please don't talk about bad practice.

Comment: "This might be a good way to decide based on your website profile, if you can apply that HTML 5 feature without a fallback for your visitors."

No it is not. For the reasons stated in the other answers. 'Browser sniffing' as it is called is bad practice. You question... and your response to almost every single answer, is based on a false assumption.

Comment: More here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971613/multiple-file-uploader-in-html5-browser-support

Answer (score 5):

Try to look at [Html5Test](http://html5test.com/) or [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/).

Comment: Html5Test is just analyzing the client browser.

Comment: This is good. Feature based progressive enhancement is rather better then doing anything browser specific.

Answer (score 3):

If it's server side, you can analyze user agent to find out if client's version supports HTML5. [Wikipedia is your friend.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)
If it's client side, there's [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library.

Comment: I'm not trying to see if my browser is supporting this but what browser version was the first to support it.

Comment: Did you look at Wikipedia link before responding?

Answer (score 3):

- A quick search gave me this interesting result (reproduced in several blogs): http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/
- And you can may also want to take a look at this list of how to detect each feature: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/everything.html
- Here is another website, quite incomplete but verbose and "work in progress" as of March 2011, so it might be worth keeping an eye on: http://html5accessibility.com/
- This one is off topic, but since I found it, I add it. CSS compatibility in IE browsers (very extensive): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx
- And here you can find info specific to the gecko engine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5
- And, of course, MDC has compatibility tables for each feature, but separated in different pages, not as a table, e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 2):

http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: modernizr.com is just analyzing the client browser.

Comment: Correct. You test your user's browser and decide based on that what you want to use, gracefully degrade in other words. You did mention in your post analyzing visitors, right?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5Test.com collects the information but they don't give detailed reports for perusal.

A good reference site for some stuff is http://www.browserscope.org/ but that doesn't go into a lot of detail with HTML5 specific support

Another source of related stuff is http://w3c-test.org/html/tests/reporting/report.htm which is creating a set of HTML testing tools that can be run.
You or someone who wanted to create this information could use these tests and then store the UA String of each browser that hit the site with the results of each test.
Then you could just find the earliest version of each browser type that a feature successfully run on.

I think this information is stored in the databases of the sites mentioned but they just don't display it which sort of sucks. Maybe try emailing them and suggesting they add these reports.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), it’s exactly what you are searching for.

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) is also a great resource, and [there is an entry](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html) for multiple files input.

Comment: looks good but can't find out info about multiple file upload

Comment: I found something but the info is in bulk for: HTML5 form features

Comment: Yes, but like I said you can't pin point support for multiple file upload, because the results are mixed.

Comment: Added QuirksMode to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for:

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus

Which i found via this blog:

http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this website](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/). I hope this is what you were looking for.