# upload image in jquery dialog

Tags: file-upload, dialog

I have an 'upload' jquery dialog box which displays a html upload form. I can't work out where to put the php form submission so I can check the code has worked. 
Also the image is being uploaded in the middle of editing a page so it is very important the page doesn't reload and the changes aren't lost (a user won't save his edits before adding the image). How do I submit the upload and keep everything within the dialog box so the page isn't reloaded and then I can make an 'insert' code to put the uploaded image in the page? 
Thanks, my code is:

```
public static function uploadImage(){
global $wgOut, $wgRequest;  

    $posted = $wgRequest->wasPosted();
    if( $posted ) {
    $wgOut->addHtml(' Maximum upload size: 2M <br />');
        }
    // form processing message set at the top if(!empty($message)){$wgOut->addHtml('$message'); }; 
    $wgOut->addHtml(' Upload an Image from your computer: <br />'); 
    $wgOut->addHtml('<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="Post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
        </form>
        '); 
$wgOut->addHtml(' Maximum upload size: 2M <br />');
$wgOut->addHtml('Permitted file types: png,gif,jpg,jpeg.'); 

}
```

jquery:

```
$("#uploadImage")
                                    .dialog({
                                    autoOpen:false,
                                    title: "Upload Image",
                                    height: "auto",
                                    width: 300
                                    });

                                $("#uploadImage").dialog("open");

                                     };
```

and

```
$wgOut->addHTML('<div id="uploadImage" style="display:none">');
     $form = self::uploadImage();   
     $wgOut->addHtml($form);
    $wgOut->addHTML('</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files using jquery post. You can use another plugin like  [ajaxfileupload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) 
It will create a tempory IFrame inside your DOM and will do the file uploading by only refreshing that IFrame.
And you can use [HTML5 file uploading](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/) you need to look at the [browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971613/multiple-file-uploader-in-html5-browser-support).
Or else you can use [flash file uploaders](http://swfupload.org/)  .

Comment: I'm trying out the ajaxfileupload but I'm not sure where to put the ajax code. I've tried to put it with the dialog box but nothing is happening: if($("#upload").is(":checked")) {        
        
        $("#uploadImage")
         .dialog({
         autoOpen:false,
         title: "Upload Image",
         height: "auto",
         width: 300
         
         .ajaxStart(function(){
                $(this).show(); })
          .ajaxComplete(function(){
                  $(this).hide();
                       })
        });

Comment: I think it's better if you append your new code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Now, 2013 Year. You **Can** upload file with ajax
But, you have to add ajaxForm Plugin,
Search it! in google